# Create empty data frame with column names by assigning a string vector?

Tags: r, dataframe

1. Create an empty data frame:

```
y <- data.frame()
```

2. Assign x, a string vector, to y as its column names:

```
    x <- c("name", "age", "gender")
    colnames(y) <- x
```

Result:

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("name", "age", "gender")) :
> 'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Actually, the x length is dynamic, so

```
y <- data.frame(name=character(), age=numeric(), gender=logical())
```

is not an efficient way to name the column. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: If you want to create an empty data.frame with dynamic names (colnames in a variable), this can help:

    names <- c("v","u","w")
    df <- data.frame()
    for (k in names) df[[k]]<-as.numeric()

You can change the type as well if you need so.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

How about:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
x <- c("name", "age", "gender")
colnames(df) <- x
```

---

To do all these operations in one-liner:

```
setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0)), c("name", "age", "gender"))

#[1] name   age    gender
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Or

```
data.frame(matrix(ncol=3,nrow=0, dimnames=list(NULL, c("name", "age", "gender"))))
```

Comment: hello, do you have an easy way to add columns (type = character) which colnames are ``` new_col_names <- c("new1", "new2") ``` ?     I tried this : ``` df[, new_col_names ] <- NULL ``` , this doesn't work

Comment: @DDchen If you have a dataframe `df`, this should work `df[new_col_names] <- NA_character_`

Comment: `setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(col), nrow = 0)), col <- c("name", "age", "gender"))` for a more dynamic way of doing it