# How to write a loop to subset data and rename the subsample

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, data-science

I have a full sample from 1986-1995 each year and 1997-2015 every other year. And it looks like:
[image]
I also have a variable lists for each year and it looks like:[image]

My purpose is to subset the whole dataset into subsample datasets for each year by using their variable names in variable lists (2nd picture).

My attempt is as following:

```
name1986 <- var_name_list$X1986
name1987 <- var_name_list$X1987
name1988 <- var_name_list$X1988
name1989 <- var_name_list$X1989
name1990 <- var_name_list$X1990
name1991 <- var_name_list$X1991
name1992 <- var_name_list$X1992
name1993 <- var_name_list$X1993
name1994 <- var_name_list$X1994
name1995 <- var_name_list$X1995
name1996 <- var_name_list$X1996
name1997 <- var_name_list$X1997
name1999 <- var_name_list$X1999
name2001 <- var_name_list$X2001
name2003 <- var_name_list$X2003
name2005 <- var_name_list$X2005
name2007 <- var_name_list$X2007
name2009 <- var_name_list$X2009
name2011 <- var_name_list$X2011
name2013 <- var_name_list$X2013
name2015 <- var_name_list$X2015
```

And it works well:
[image]
However I got stuck in the following:

```
seq_yr = c(seq(1986,1996),seq(1997,2015,by=2))
for (Number in seq_yr){
  dataname <- sprintf("name",Number)
  file<- subset(data,select = c(ID,which(colnames(data) %in% dataname)))
  # assign value to the variable name x 
  assign(x=str_c("data.",Number),value=file,envir=.GlobalEnv)  
}
```

This successfully gives me a few subsample datasets but each of them only includes one variable. And this is what shows in my workspace:

[image]

Could you please let me know what went wrong with my code?

I would like to attach the part of my data in the following link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=19KMl6eNsCEfcRJxWGoyWJSb34kPhmJaW

data4 is the data and header4 is the part of variable lists.

Thanks a lot!!! Please comment if you have any concerns regarding my question.

Comment: Please use `dput` to make your data reproducible. Then we can work off your existing data rather than create a new set. Nice writeup though.

Comment: sorry about that. Let me try to revise this.

Comment: Hi @Fangzhu, if your data file is that big, often times it's better to do a write.csv(). I tried copying and pasting your `dput` data and while I'm sure it will work, it was troublesome getting a good format. Also, you did not provide a file extension to your google drive files. Try a write.csv(df, "df_raw.csv") and name the other one `def_keys`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, you'd like to do the following:

1. Develop the base case
2. Turn the base case into a function
3. Scale for the generic solution

Let's go through them, but first, a reproducible example:

```
> df_raw <- data.frame(v1 = 1:10, v2 = 11:20, v3 = 21:30, v4 = 31:40, v5 = 41:50, v6 = 51:60)
> 
> df_keys <- data.frame(colNames = c('name1', 'name2', 'name3'),
+                       year1 = c('v1', 'v2', 'v3'),
+                       year2 = c('v4','v5','v6'))
> 
> 
> df_raw
   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1   1 11 21 31 41 51
2   2 12 22 32 42 52
3   3 13 23 33 43 53
4   4 14 24 34 44 54
5   5 15 25 35 45 55
6   6 16 26 36 46 56
7   7 17 27 37 47 57
8   8 18 28 38 48 58
9   9 19 29 39 49 59
10 10 20 30 40 50 60
> df_keys
  colNames year1 year2
1    name1    v1    v4
2    name2    v2    v5
3    name3    v3    v6
```

### Base Case

Always start with your base case. Create an [empty data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712301/create-empty-data-frame-with-column-names-by-assigning-a-string-vector) and change the names to the column names to make it readable. The first column of your df_key data frame shows variable names, and the second one shows *one* year of variable names.

```
> colNames <- df_keys[,1]
> yearNames <- df_keys[,2]
> new_df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(yearNames), nrow = 0))
> new_df <- df_raw[,yearNames]
> names(new_df) <- colNames
> new_df
   name1 name2 name3
1      1    11    21
2      2    12    22
3      3    13    23
4      4    14    24
5      5    15    25
6      6    16    26
7      7    17    27
8      8    18    28
9      9    19    29
10    10    20    30
```

### Create a Function

Honestly, this is the easiest step. Just put brackets around it and rename a few key names.

```
subDF <- function(df_raw, df_keys, nameIndex = 1, yearIndex = 2){

  colnames <- df_keys[,nameIndex]
  yearNames <- df_keys[,yearIndex]
  new_df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(yearNames), nrow = 0))
  new_df <- df_raw[,yearNames]
  names(new_df) <- colNames
  new_df
}

> subDF(df_raw, df_keys)
   name1 name2 name3
1      1    11    21
2      2    12    22
3      3    13    23
4      4    14    24
5      5    15    25
6      6    16    26
7      7    17    27
8      8    18    28
9      9    19    29
10    10    20    30
```

### Scale

This can be one of many methods. It's simple enough to have two statements.

```
> allYears <- seq(dim(df_keys)[2]-1)+1
> lapply(allyears, function(x) {subDF(df_raw, df_keys, yearIndex = x)})
[[1]]
   name1 name2 name3
1      1    11    21
2      2    12    22
3      3    13    23
4      4    14    24
5      5    15    25
6      6    16    26
7      7    17    27
8      8    18    28
9      9    19    29
10    10    20    30

[[2]]
   name1 name2 name3
1      1    11    21
2      2    12    22
3      3    13    23
4      4    14    24
5      5    15    25
6      6    16    26
7      7    17    27
8      8    18    28
9      9    19    29
10    10    20    30
```