# Shift column names across by 10 columns

Tags: r, plyr, rvest

I have the following code to import some data.

```
url <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/industry/Scientific_Technical_Instruments"

library(rvest)

read <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_table() 

library(plyr)

data <- ldply(read, data.frame)
```

However the data creates a data frame of 20 columns when there should be just 10. The column names of the data frame have not imported as they should and creates a number of NA values.

Is there a way in R to shift the column names across, then remove the NA columns created?

Comment: if you think that one of the replies helped you, could you approve one of them as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your object `read` is a list with headers as the first element and data as the second. Your problem is that your column names in `read[[1]]` are not syntactically valid names for data frame columns.

You need to sanitise your names by using `make.names`. E.g.

```
data <- data.frame(read[[2]]) 
names(data) <- make.names(names(read[[1]])
```

An one-liner version for this can be found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712301/create-empty-data-frame-with-column-names-by-assigning-a-string-vector/32712555).

```
data <- setNames(data.frame(read[[2]]), make.names(names(read[[1]])))
```

Comment: oh, I see what the problem is now!

Comment: a mix of our approaches: `setNames(data.frame(read[[2]]), colnames(read[[1]]))`

Answer (score 1):

```
my_data <- data.frame(read[[2]])
colnames(my_data) <- colnames(read[[1]])
```