# How to convert a vector to become variable names in an R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

What I am trying to do is hopefully very simple. I have a vector of names that are to become the variable names in a data frame. The end result is a data frame with (initially) no data, but with 210 named variables as per the vector called "label". Any ideas as to how to do this?

```
vector0 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
vector1 <- rep(1:3, times=1, each=70)
vector2 <- rep(1:5, times=1, each=14)
vector3 <- rep(1:2, times=1, each=7)
label <- paste(vector0, vector1, vector2, vector3, sep="")
```

Comment: `df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 210)), label)` would work ? Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712301/create-empty-data-frame-with-column-names-by-assigning-a-string-vector/

Comment: It's not clear to me what the end result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "no data", so I suppose you want a data frame without any data, not even NA's:

```
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(210, numeric()))
```

Now you're ready to change the names:

```
names(df) <- label # `label` from OP
```

Or in one shot:

```
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(replicate(210, numeric())), label)
```